# How to disable "Simplify geometry" via Python?

Tags: qgis, python, geometry, layers, simplify

After I've loaded a layer from a table in my db I'd like to disable the 'Simplify geometry' (found in Layers/Properties/Rendering) programatically using Python.
I've tried several versions of QgsVectorSimplifyMethod.SimplifyHint

```
current_layer = iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
if current_layer:
  try:
    current_layer.setSimplifyMethod(QgsVectorSimplifyMethod.setSimplifyHints(QgsVectorSimplifyMethod.SimplifyHint.NoSimplification))
  catch Exception, e:
      print e
```

but can't get the usage of QgsVectorSimplifyMethod.SimplifyHint.NoSimplification correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a bug in setSimplifyHints?

```
>>>current_layer.simplifyMethod().setSimplifyHints(QgsVectorSimplifyMethod.NoSimplification)

>>>int(current_layer.simplifyMethod().simplifyHints()) == QgsVectorSimplifyMethod.NoSimplification
False

>>>int(current_layer.simplifyMethod().simplifyHints()) == QgsVectorSimplifyMethod.GeometrySimplification 
True
```

After manually removing simplify geometry through the dialog
[image]

```
int(current_layer.simplifyMethod().simplifyHints()) == QgsVectorSimplifyMethod.NoSimplification
True
```

Looks like the simplifyHints does not set the simplification mode. I quess you need to calculate a precise area since you want no geometry simplification. Can you test against your database if simplify does affect any area calculation in QGIS. You can use your PostGIS db to return the area also.

Comment: I would not know how to test it myself. I will however ask the person requesting the disabling of simplify geometry to test this.

Answer (score 1):

As Jakob pointed out, `layer.simplifyMethod().setSimplifyHints(...)` doesn't seem to allow changing the simplification method.

In order to change the simplification method for a layer using Python, you can instead create a new `QgsVectorSimplifyMethod()` object, set the simplification method for that object to `NoSimplification`, and assign the object to the layer using  `layer.setSimplifyMethod`:

```py
mNoSimplification = QgsVectorSimplifyMethod()
mNoSimplification.setSimplifyHints(QgsVectorSimplifyMethod.NoSimplification)
layer.setSimplifyMethod(mNoSimplification)
```